# Can I dynamically remove a class set by a library?

Tags: css, react-quill

I am using react-quill to add a text formatter in my application. The library add classes to li tags if it finds indentation. Below is an example:

```
   <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li class="ql-indent-1">Sub  First</li>
      <li class="ql-indent-2">Sub sub first</li>
   </ul>
```

The result will be as below

```
     - First
       - Sub First
         - Sub sub first
```

Basically based on the classes, the library adds the indentation. I want to dynamically remove ql-indent-2. If the user presses tab for second level bullet point, no class should be added instead of ql-indent-2 being appended to class. Is this possible?